# Urllib2 throws 404 but page works

Tags: python, urllib2

The following page works on chrome: http://www.proskauer.com/professionals/joel-cavanaugh/.

However, when I access it via urllib2, I get a 404.

```
urllib2.urlopen("http://www.proskauer.com/professionals/joel-cavanaugh/").read()
```

I have tried to alter the user agent via the following code, but still get a 404:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open("http://www.proskauer.com/professionals/joel-cavanaugh/")
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Your code works for me, but does not with no user agent.

Comment: Your user-agent code also works for me. Are you sure the code you have here is the same code that you're trying (with the addition of response.read())? Note that this is a user agent issue, not a Python one: curl gives a 404 without a user agent as well. You may want to try a full user-agent, which may be a factor in other cases, but is not in this.

Comment: My code may be different.  What do you mean by a full user agent?

Comment: One copied from either a list or a browser. For example, my current one: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36` . But your exact code in your question appears to work fine for everyone else.